# Time Series for Regression

Tags: data-request, time-series

I am searching for time series data for regression problems. To clarify: I want to do machine learning on a time series and predict a single real continuous value for each time series, but I do not want to do forecasting (so I do not want to predict the next value in the time series).

An example would be to predict the lifetime of different components, which are monitored by sensors.

Does anyone have a good idea, where to get such data (does not have to be the component example)?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php?format=&task=&att=&area=&numAtt=&numIns=&type=ts&sort=nameUp&view=table